# Inversed foreign key doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, orm, doctrine

i have a OneToOne relation between my entity User and UserMeta

i would like to have access to UserMeta in User but set the foreign key in the UserMeta table in my mysql database:

```
class User implements UserInterface{

   /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", unique=true)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Foo\Bar\Entity\UserMeta", cascade={"persist"}, inversedBy="id_user")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_pro")
     */
    private $proData;
}


class UserMeta{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", unique=true)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Foo\Bar\Entity\User", mappedBy="id_pro")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_user")
     */
    private $user;
}
```

Anyway to do that with doctrine ? I think i misunderstood mapped and inversed properties.

Comment: Hi @MarcD, I wrote a post few months ago regarding one to one mapping. It tells you about the inversed by attribute too. If you are interested here is the link. http://anjanasilva.com/blog/one-to-one-relationship-mapping-using-doctrine-2/

Comment: I looked at your tuto, but you still have program_details_id in your program table no ?

Comment: product_details_id is the current tables's (product) column name which you referenced to to the target table's (product_details) primary key. Or in best case scenario, you can map current table's primary key with the target's tables primary key.

Comment: So i can't have a productDetails (in php) in my product object without having the foreign key in the product table ?I just want to have the program id in the program_details table but i don't care about bidirectionnal relation.

Comment: If you mentioned mappedBy or inversedBy it expects the mapped by or inversed by bit from the target entity. Assume you are relating from table A to table B. To form a basic relationship you mention the oneToOne / oneToMany / etc in the Entity A. But if you mention inversedBy or mappedBy in Entity A, you need to have matching mappedBy (if inversed) or inversedBy (if mapped) attribute in the Entity B. Hope you got the point. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You mapping configuration is wrong.

In your User Class, it should read:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Foo\Bar\Entity\UserMeta", cascade={"persist"}, inversedBy="user")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 */
private $proData;
```

and in your UserMeta Class, it should read:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Foo\Bar\Entity\User", mappedBy="proData")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 */
private $user;
```

You also don't need the @ORM\Column directive since Doctrine2 will automatically do it for you.